# Is it possible to query or modify project membership/guests with the Asana API?

Tags: asana

I'd like to be able to add a user as a guest to a project specific to that individual, but it looks like I cannot do this programmatically and must instead resort to manually adding them as a guest. Is there anything I'm missing in the API documentation? Is there an undocumented feature that would let me do so? Or am I just out of luck?

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to manage users of an organization via the API.

This is on our API roadmap, which I hope to publish a public version of soon.

You can subscribe to incremental changes of our API and it's documentation on API changelog https://www.apichangelog.com/api/asana