# How can I add guests or members to projects created through the Asana API?

Tags: asana, asana-api

I currently have a script that takes a list of people and creates new Asana projects, one for each person. These people are not in our Asana organization and need to be invited as guests to their respective projects. If I try to include a `followers` or `members` property in my API request, I get denied, and the docs list those properties as `read-only`.

I noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378986/is-it-possible-to-query-or-modify-project-membership-guests-with-the-asana-api) from over a year and a half ago, where an Asana engineer said that it was on the API roadmap and that he hoped to publish it soon. It seems like the engineer in question no longer works at Asana, so replying to him won't help me, but has any progress been made on this front? Being able to invite guests to each project programmatically would be a huge time saver.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We decided to keep this as a read-only endpoint. Apologies for the confusion.

You can [add and remove followers on a task](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks#followers) through the API.  Perhaps you could adjust your workflow to use tasks instead of projects.