# How can I add a user to organization in ASANA via API?

Tags: asana, invite, asana-api, asana-connect

I'd like to add a new user to ASANA programmatically. I already have the OAUTH App and the user token.

Looking at the API I can't find a way to "create a new user".

Is it possible to create a new user simple via API?

Otherwise, is it possible to "invite" a new user via given email? Like from the UI where you can put the EMAIL and the system send an invitation link!

I tried with:

```
 https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces/[WORKSPACEID]/addUser?user=[NEW USER EMAIL]
```

But I get a BAD REQUEST in response:

```
 {
"errors": [
    {
        "message": "Could not parse request data, invalid JSON",
        "help": "For more information on API status codes and how to handle them, read the docs on errors: https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/errors"
    }
]
```

}

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried to do that specifically, but recently I did attempt to add members to a project through the API. There was nothing in the documentation about it, and I was told that [it wasn't a supported API operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43104103/how-can-i-add-guests-or-members-to-projects-created-through-the-asana-api/43219714#43219714).

I would guess that if there's no mention of this feature in the documentation that it's also not supported for a similar reason.